# Getting Beaker working with GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, bottle, beaker

I'm trying to port an app I've been running locally to GAE.  The app uses the Bottle.py framework.  I use Beaker for session management.  I'm a bit of a noob and am having trouble getting Beaker imported properly. Help greatly appreciated.

I'm running the ported app using GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app under Mac OS X 10.6.7.  This runs the app in the simulation environment on my machine, not on Google's servers.

For my GAE port, I've put Bottle.py into a directory called 'framework'. This directory has an empty `__init__.py` file.  Bottle is working fine and can serve 'hello world'.

Beaker exists in its own directory in the root of my app (journal/beaker).  Beaker also has an empty `__init__.py`.

Relevant code:

```
from framework import bottle
from beaker import SessionMiddleware
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

@bottle.route('/')
def index():
    return "hello, world"

def main():
    bottle.debug(True)
    run_wsgi_app(bottle.default_app())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I get an error message like this:

```
File "/Users/mscantland/code/journal/main.py", line 19, in <module>
    from beaker import SessionMiddleware
ImportError: cannot import name SessionMiddleware
```

Here is what I have tried to get this working so far:

- Checked permissions on everything in /beaker to make sure they were executable.
- Ran beaker as-is and also re-wrote all import statements so that:

  from beaker.x import y

became:

```
from x import y
```

- Added 'pkg_resources.py' which is not in the standard library for the Python version GAE uses.

Comment: I use beaker like in the answer i.e. `from beaker.middleware import SessionMiddleware` having the directory named beaker in the same directory as my gae app. The beaker session works but I couldn't get it to work with template unless passing the variable i.e. the beaker session is not avaible in the template from the requiest.session or likewise.

Answer (score 0):

SessionMiddleware is in middleware.py. Try:

```
from beaker.middleware import SessionMiddleware
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried that and it moves the problem:

    File "/Users/mscantland/code/journal/beaker/pkg_resources.py", line 28, in <module>
    from os import utime, rename, unlink, mkdir
    ImportError: cannot import name mkdir

Comment: Your point is very valid though--you are correct that SessionMiddleware is in middleware.py.

Comment: You can't write to FileSystem on GAE and some modules/functions with such abilities are disabled. `os.mkdir` happens to be one of them.

Comment: Thanks Eren.  I'll check this out today.

Comment: Even though I really like bottle, I decided that using it rather than Google's webapp framework and Users service was pushing a rope uphill when working with GAE.  So I've moved over to webapp and Users.

Answer (score 0):

I answered my question by re-approaching the problem with webapp and Google's Users service which has better documentation for working with GAE.